# Why doesn't my array store any input values?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to input any number into array `b[]` by number of `numCase` times.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//entry point

int main()

{


//Declarations

int b[20]; // array size 20 ( limit of inputs)
int c = 0;
int numCase;
int input;





 cout << "ENTER NUMBER OF CASES (MAXIMUM NUMBER OF 20):  \n";
 cin >> numCase;


//checks that numCase is less than or equal to (20) and does not exceed
if (numCase < 21)
        {



// gets input number based on the numCase

do
{


cout << "ENTER A NUMBER (MAXIMUM OF 5 DIGITS): \n";
                cin >> input;
                cout << "\n";
                b[c] = input;
                c++;



} while (c != numCase);


cout << b[c] ;  //  this is my problem it OUTPUTS RANDOM VALUE, 
     //but i can  see on my watch list that b has the values of my input.
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're filling entries `0` to`N` of `b`, and then printing entry `N+1`, which you haven't filled in.

Comment: what changes should i make?

Comment: Print entry of index one less than when printing b[c]

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c` should be initialised back to zero.

```
} while (c != numCase);

c = 0;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion i initialized c to 0 after the while loop but when i cout b[c] all i got was the first input. say i wanted 2 inputs 
ex. 20 and 700 my cout only displayed 20.

Comment: Yes - best use a for loop and increment a counter to display all array elements.

Comment: should i want to use if statements i.e. if ( b[counter] <101) and my inputs are 20 and 700. how do i make sure that 700 doesn't get inside that statement? i've tried it 700 does get inside

Comment: `if (b[counter] <= 700)` ?

Comment: the problem is that 700 is not less than 101 already, but since b[counter] also contains 20 it also runs 700 inside the statement, what can i do to make sure that doesn't happened?

Comment: Best you post a new question about your current problem :)

Answer (score 0):

cout << b[c] ; // in this statement c already reached to numCase where you have not assigned any value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all the numbers stored in array b[]
then you may write your code as

```
for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
{ if(b[i]<101)   //This will exclude all the values which are greater than 101
   {cout<<"\n"<<b[i];}}
```

Comment: i've tried the for loop and it does display all my inputs. but should i want to use if statements i.e. if ( b[counter] <101) and my inputs are 20 and 700. how do i make sure that 700 doesn't get inside that statement? i've tried it 700 does get inside

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope you might want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
for (int i=0; i<numCase; i++)
{
    if(b[i] >= x) //x is a variable that u can set as a limit. eg. 700
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<b[i];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps